# How to make the modal close by clicking anywhere outside of the modal-window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm currently working on [this](http://1ne-studio.com/test2/) website.

and I would like to add extra function where users can close the modal
(which could be opened at the top-right corner of the grey sub-header)
by clicking anywhere except for the modal box.

Right now I can only close the modal when I click close at the top-right corner of the modal box or the black background.

How could I make this possible?

Comment: it closes when I clock on the side.. background. you achieved it meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

You can set bigger value of `z-index` to black overlay (`#modal-overlay`) to make it appear above other elements.

For test reasons you can test this code in console :

```
$('#modal-overlay').css('z-index', 10000);
$('#modal-name, #modal-movies').css('z-index', 10001);
```

Of course you should set it in CSS and choose more reasonable z-index values ;)